# How can i implement tiles in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am using servlet & jsp and I want to integrate tiles with it. 
Can you give me example so that I can easily use it. I integrated tiles with struts and spring but didn't use with servlet. Is it possible to integrate tiles with servlet and jsp.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather check the documentation on the tiles website then?

Comment: I read one article from: http://tiles.apache.org/2.1/framework/tutorial/configuration.html                                           Starting Tiles in a web application

Tiles has always been a web application package, usually used in conjunction with Struts. Tiles 2 evolved to the point of being technology-independent, but its use in a Servlet-based web application will be the most frequent use case.